# Ember data: What technology is used to store the data in browser?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I recently discovered ember-data (https://github.com/emberjs/data) and it's really impressive.

Somebody know what technology ember-data use to store the data in the browser (WebSQL, IndexedDB,..???) - i don't find any hint in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember-Data is completely agnostic to your persistence layer, so you can choose any one you'd like. You just have to create an [Adapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html).

This information can all be found in the [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/customizing-adapters/).

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data is not storing data in the browser permanently. It's just in RAM. Close the browser and the Ember data "store" is gone. Ember-Data is simply a really nice way to work with a model layer in your Ember app.

Its main function is to keep data around between state changes in your ember app so you don't have to manage the model layer yourself, and so you don't do silly things like multiple call outs to your data store API for things you've already got.

It's not finished yet, though, so usual beta/alpha-software caveats apply.